# Connecting to TFS17 From VSPACKAGE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, vsix, vspackage

I have some problem with connection my visual studio extension to TFS17. This my code:

```
       List<BuildDefinitionReference> bds = new List<BuildDefinitionReference>();
        Uri _uri = new Uri("http://my_uri....");
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential _credentials = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(true);
        BuildHttpClient _client = new BuildHttpClient(_uri, new VssCredentials(_credentials));
```

At last line I received this exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll but was not handled in user code
  Additional information: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'.
```

I have no problems with assemblies because I checked them all and I fixed all versions. This same piece of code works in a simple console application! The problem is vspackage.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is come dependency with Json package. try unistalling the Nuget package: Newtonsoft.Json

[Update]
Try insatlling this package first wrt the required version :
// Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client -Version xx.xxx 
Then import followinging in the code...

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common; 
using System.Net;
```

Also These Packages :
// Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version xx.xx

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
```

Comment: I did this. It's impossibile that I have problems with assembly becouse the same assembly configuration e the same piece of code works in a console application.

Comment: Try insatlling this package first wrt the required version // Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client -Version xx.xxx
Then import followinging in the code...using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using System.Net;
// Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version xx.xx
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

Comment: I found that this is my situation. The assembly that are loaded are Json 6 and Json 8 : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5b088f-8157-45ab-8862-6b4e5283d6cf/newtonsoftjson-vs-package?forum=vsx

But I don't understand how can I fix

Comment: @blinkettaro Do you use VS 2015? Did you try the solution in the link you provided: "add a configuration file as content of VS package that contains the assembly redirection to Json.net 8.0 and set this configuration file to new AppDomain"?

Comment: @blinkettaro If you also install Newtonsoft.Json 6.0 with Nuget, how's the result?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using VS2015 which will cause this issue since devenv.exe.config for it has bindingRedirect to Newtonsoft.Json 6.0 version.

```
<dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

When you run your code in console application, it used the config file for your console app rather then the devenv.exe.config, that's why it works.

Upgrade your VS to the latest 2017 version, you should not see this issue any more since 2017 use Newtonsoft.Json 9.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, put these assemblies beside your assembly: `Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll` & `Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll`